# Commands to compile programs on Windows

Tags: .net, command-line, compiler-construction, command

In case I have .NET framework installed in my computer + all the necessary other language support (Perl Interpreter, etc)

What are the commands I should give in the console to compile programs in the following languages:
1. C
2. C++
3. Java
4. Python
5. VB
6. C#
7. Perl
8. Ruby

Like we have for VB- *vbc program_name.vb*, what are the commands to compile programs in other languages?

Comment: By "run programs in the following languages", do you mean *compile*?

Comment: yeah thats what he means. vbc is just the way to call the vb.net compiler from the command line with the filename as the argument.

Comment: We're confused - do you want to compile .NET assemblies in languages such as Perl, or do you want to compile other types of programs in their 'normal' language, such as java source files into .jar files with the java compiler?  (Your first sentence "In case I have .NET framework installed in my computer + all the necessary other language support (Perl Interpreter, etc)" is confusing me).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- C and C++: cl
- Java: javac
- Python: python or pythonw
- VB: vbc
- C#: csc
- Ruby: ruby

Comment: For Java, Python, and Ruby, what you are giving are interpreters, not compilers. For Java, the closest you can get to compile it for .Net is J# (which is Java syntax with .Net APIs, couldn't use the "Java" name because MS had been sued by Sun for some license violations). For Python and Ruby, there are .Net- based implementations known as IronPython and IronRuby; but I don't know if they can be actually "compiled".

Comment: But I think we completely misunderstood.  I think he's asking compile MSIL from Perl or Python source, ie: Perl.Net etc.

Comment: @Michael: @herenvardo: I think he just wants the compile commands. I don't think this has anything to do with MSIL.

Comment: @herenvardo  I would disagree with your assertion that Java isn't compiled.  True, it isn't (by javac) compiled into native code (it is often JIT compiled into native code though) but javac does translate the high-level language into bytecode and store it in class files.  This is in contrast to a language like python or lisp that is interpreted.  That is, the execution environment operates directly on the code written by the developer rather than on an intermediate form (bytecode).

Comment: @Joel I think you nailed what the OP was looking for

Comment: @John: the mention to .Net at the start of the post, plus the .Net tagging, made me think he's looking for .Net compilation, but a clarification by the OP would be really useful here.
@Chris: the answer was edited after my comment. Before that, it listed java/javaw, which are interpreters (bytecode interpreters, but still not compilers). Looking deeper at it, it looks like the OP originally asked for "interpreters", while he meant "compilers", so it makes sense that Joel provided a list of interpreters on his answer.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like `devenv`?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xee0c8y7%28VS.71%29.aspx